# Reset password was performed in Azure MySQL, but admin privileges are not restored

Tags: azure-database-mysql

I am unable to get the list of all the databases as it looks like my Azure Admin user privileges have been revoked after the admin user password was changed through the admin portal.
If I log into the Azure portal then I can see all the databases but through the Client Application like WorkBench - Admin users don't see any databases.
Please advise how to resolve this as it has been working fine prior to the admin password was changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you followed to reset the password by you is unknown at this moment. I would like to suggest you follow the procedure mentioned below.

[image]

then after clicking on reset password, change the password.

[image]

- If the password is **reset**, the admin privileges will reset to default. that is the natural agenda. If the issue is still active, it is suggestable to raise the ticket to the support system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have followed the exact same path to reset the admin password from the Azure Portal since then i have lost access to see all the databases when login in through Client Application WorkBench or any other client application. I have also tried Azure CLI, also it do not have any database under the admin login. However, when I navigate the left menu  in Azure "Databases" then i do see all the databases.  How to give admin user permission to view all databases. ?

Comment: Then it must be the case to contact the support team once as some of the automatic operations are deprecated after reset. Try to raise the ticket to the support system regarding this.